# Generated code from matlab curve fitting tool doesn't match original curve

Tags: matlab

I used matlab's CFtool to generate a fit based on a custom function, however, when I generate that code and call it to my main script file the curves are slightly different. My generated code does not cross the y -int, although it does in CFtool. Does any body know what the issue is? I have tried setting different start points and it didn't change anything.

Suggestions

Generated code:

```
%% Fit: 'untitled fit 1'.
[xData, yData] = prepareCurveData( I100M, P100M );

% Set up fittype and options.
ft = fittype( 'a*tanh(-b*x/300)+c', 'independent', 'x', 'dependent', 'y' );
opts = fitoptions( 'Method', 'NonlinearLeastSquares' );
opts.Display = 'Off';
opts.StartPoint = [0.990128346443291 0.106912965297856 0.94637904214048];

% Fit model to data.
[fitresult, gof] = fit( xData, yData, ft, opts );

% Plot fit with data.
figure( 'Name', 'untitled fit 1' );
h = plot( fitresult, xData, yData );
```

[CFtool fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMpYd.jpg)

[generated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKfxG.jpg)

Comment: They look the same to me. Its just that your plot doesn't go as far into the negative direction of the x-axis as the CFTool. If you made the axes of both plots the same, you will see the same thing.

Comment: Ah!! I did rescale axes, but my lines of code were out of place. Great, thanks...my brain has been fried with this.